# CSS One column on mobile, two on desktop

Tags: html, css

I've got a page with 1 column on mobile and 2 columns on desktop. On mobile I want to follow the order of the elements in the HTML (article 1, article 2, article 3, article 4).

On desktop I want to stack all items with the class left-column in the left column and all items with the class right-column in the right column.

So in the example below, I want to show in the left column: article1, article 3, article 4. And in the right column article 2 and article 5.

Requirements:

- The content of an article varies (not all article have the same height)
- I don't want a gap between article 2 & 5 in the right column (or gaps between articles in the left column)
- All borders must be shown
- There should be a margin between the left and right column
- The order of the articles in the html cannot be changed

```css
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {

    /* no idea what to do here */

}

/* rest of styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
}
h1 + p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
article {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="left-column">
    <h1>Article 1</h1>
    <p>Shown in left column</p>
  </article>
  <article class="right-column">
    <h1>Article 2</h1>
    <p>Shown in right column</p>
  </article>
  <article class="left-column">
    <h1>Article 3</h1>
    <p>Shown in left column</p>
  </article>
  <article class="left-column">
    <h1>Article 4</h1>
    <p>Shown in left column</p>
  </article>
  <article class="right-column">
    <h1>Article 5</h1>
    <p>Shown in right column</p>
  </article>
</div>
```

**update**

To be clear. I don't want the result to be like this:
[image: Not good]
But like this:
[image: Good]

Comment: tried `visible-xs` and `hidden-xs` classes ? will they be useful ?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to show all articles on mobile and desktop, don't want to hide anything.

Comment: @Vikrant , he is not using Bootstrap.

Comment: okay , if you are using bootstrap you can see grid view , you can adjust your view according to screen using its classes , check this . http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bootstrap-Responsive-GridView-for-Mobile-Phone-Tablet-and-Desktop-display-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx  and  http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/list-grid-view

Comment: In Bootstrap it's not possible, I end up with a gap between article 2 and 5.

Comment: Can the html change structure?

Comment: Would using javascript/jQuery be okay?

Comment: The html structure might change, but the order might not be changed

Comment: No javascript / jquery

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to accomplish this without some scripting. I can't see this working with styles only. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using bootstrap.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      article 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      article 2
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      article 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      article 4
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      article 5
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      
    </div>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use bootstrap, but even if I do want to use it, it's not solving my problem.

I don't want any gaps between the content. If in you're example article 4 becomes bigger, then I have a gap between article 3 and article 5.

Comment: I knew he did not want to use bootstrap. But I am using Bootstrap and this answer what was I needed, so...

Answer (score 0):

I think all of the sections marked left-column should be floated left and all right-column should be floated right. You may need to monkey with the souce order to get the order right. Then set their widths to 20% or so and fiddle with the widths and margin values until they sit correctly. In mobile view, you can retain the floats, but set all widths to 100%.  And don't forget to clear all the floats afterwards.

Comment: I already tried using left and right floats, but if I use them I will either get a gap between article 2 and 5 or the articles are not shown in the correct collumn.

Answer (score 0):

it work for me

**my css**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 20rem) {
  .left, .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 70rem) {
  .left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

**my html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">
        LEFT
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        RIGHT
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add CSS:

```
.wrapper {
      margin-right: -15px;
      margin-left: -15px;
 }
.left-column, .right-column {
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .left-column, .right-column {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Now Article 4 is shown in the right column (it should be in the left) and article 5 is in the left column (it should be in the right)

Comment: If you want to last column right side so add this class "pull-right" on last column and add css ".pull-right: float:right"

Answer (score -1):

Have a read through the responsive CSS section on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp).

Adding rows and columns to your HTML will lay it out how you want it, and resize to full screen on smaller mobile devices.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
}
h1 + p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
article {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <article class="col-6">
      <h1>Article 1</h1>
      <p>Shown in left column</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-6">
      <h1>Article 2</h1>
      <p>Shown in right column</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <article class="col-6">
      <h1>Article 3</h1>
      <p>Shown in left column</p>
    </article>
    <article class="col-6">
      <h1>Article 4</h1>
      <p>Shown in left column</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <article class="col-6">
      <h1>Article 5</h1>
      <p>Shown in right column</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: article 4 is showing in the right column and article 5 in the right left column, that's not what I want to achieve